# What's the difference between Fulcrum Racing 3 and Fulcrum Racing S3?

Tags: rims

I'm able to buy a set of Fulcrum Racing S3 wheels.  I searched in all their on line catalogues but the wheels in the picture the guy send me are nowhere to be found.
I'm thinking these are exclusively made for Specialized bikes, could this be true?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the Racing 3 and the racing S3 is that the racing S3 is a 35mm deep aero wheel and the racing 3 is a more shallow lighter wheel.

Comment: Do you have links for those? The question should include them, but if not the answer should.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I could not find them anywhere and I tried hard.

My 2015 Allez Pro has these wheels and they are great, slightly heavy but a solid all around performer! I'm happy with them and pretty sure they are made for specialized because they don't exist online.